# Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '_TasksListState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>' Receiver: Closure: (bool) => Null

Tags: flutter, dart, callback, flutter-onpressed

task_list.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todoey_app/widgets/task_tile.dart';
import 'package:todoey_app/models/task.dart';

class TasksList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<TasksList> createState() => _TasksListState();
}

class _TasksListState extends State<TasksList> {
  List<Task> tasks = [
    Task(name: 'Buy milk'),
    Task(name: 'Buy eggs'),
    Task(name: 'Buy bread'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return TaskTile(
            taskTitle: tasks[index].name,
            isChecked: tasks[index].isDone,
            checkboxCallback: (bool checkboxState) {
              setState(() {
                tasks[index].toggleDone();
              });
            });
      },
      itemCount: tasks.length,
    );
  }
}
```

task_tile.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TaskTile extends StatelessWidget {
  late final bool isChecked;
  late final String taskTitle;
  final Function checkboxCallback;

  TaskTile(
      {required this.isChecked,
      required this.taskTitle,
      required this.checkboxCallback});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        taskTitle,
        style: TextStyle(
            decoration: isChecked ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null),
      ),
      trailing: Checkbox(
        activeColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        value: isChecked,
        onChanged: checkboxCallback(),
        // onChanged: toggleCheckboxState(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDlLx.jpg)

Inside the checkbox in on changed property is not working with the check box call back method. Do you know what i have done wrong here? As per my online instructor it was working on her older version of dart but seems it's not working now in the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Using `onChanged: checkboxCallback()` will call the method while building frame, you can use `onChanged: checkboxCallback,` and it will get calls when the item will be get changed.

Comment: It worked. I was actually able to not writer () after checkboxCallback by keeping my checkboxCallback variable type dynamic.